# view the code of methods in a python module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have imported some python module and I would like to view the implementation of some of the module methods. How can I do this?

I tried `inspect.getsource`, however, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 701, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 690, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 529, in findsource
    raise IOError('source code not available')
IOError: source code not available
```

Comment: Not all modules are implemented in Python. You can only get the source code for modules that have actual Python source code.

Comment: Which module(s) are you trying to inspect? [*"An IOError is raised if the source code cannot be retrieved"*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource); this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: the module is originally written in java. Is there a way around that?

Comment: If a Python module was written in Java, you were probably shipped only the Java bytecode. You might try finding those bytecode files and decompiling them, but that's tricky hacking and probably won't help you too much.